# Is it possible for manually to add crashlytics frame and it working

Tags: swift, crash, crashlytics

I'm added Crashlytics for my iOS app. I downloaded  framework from it via their site link, and went through all the steps for integrating the frameworks, adding the run script, etc.but problem is that i add framework in manually and not receiving a email.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#add-sdk) to manually add the Crashlytics SDK?

Did you also integrate the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks)?

To use Firebase Crashlytics, you also need to install the Firebase SDK along with the related configuration. E.g. Installing the GoogleService-Info.plist file and the initialization code.

Once you do this, you will need to cause a crash. For this, you need to run the app, stop Xcode, and from the device run the app and cause the crash. Then you will need to run the app again from the device. If everything was done correctly, then you should see the report in your Crashlytics console.